# php multiple AND Select Query

Tags: php, sql, select

Hi There I'm trying to get some data with this SELECT statement and when I just select two items it gives me result but when I place third item it doesn't give any result.

```
$Query="SELECT * from tableName WHERE status='true' AND gid='".$gid."' AND section='".$cid."'";
```

Plz any solution.

this one works fine, but when I add third item status='true'. doesn't work.

```
$Query="SELECT * from tableName WHERE gid='".$gid."' AND section='".$cid."'";
```

Comment: Which one is the third item? Show us the query that doesn't work and the one that does work.

Comment: doesn't return data. Just wondering it the above Query with double AND condition fine?

Comment: You're query is fine. What data type is contained in the 'status' column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me say this: Double-quoted strings can parse your variables, so this line can work, too:

```
$Query="SELECT * from tableName WHERE gid='$gid' AND SECTION='$cid'";
```

Try to learn PHP basics about using single `'` and double `"` quotes here: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/4321181)

Related to the database query, is `status` field is present in your database table? If not, it should NOT be included within the database, or it will return `FALSE` boolean value. Instead, use `IF` if you want to be 'selectively' filtering the status of the table.

```
if('your conditions here'){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE gid='$gid' AND section='$cid'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is the *status='true'*

probable the database control its field with 1 or 0 value.

Comment: if 'status' is an string field, check with 'link' instead of '='